# What SSD external drive with hardware encryption support Ubuntu?

Tags: encryption, ssd

I searched around, as far as I know, I don't find SSD external drives with hardware encryption that support Ubuntu.
For example, all below do not support Ubuntu.
Samsung T3/T5 Portable SSD 
Seagate Expansion 1TB Portable External Hard Drive USB 3.0 (STEA1000400)
WD 1TB Black My Passport  Portable External Hard Drive - USB 3.0 - WDBYNN0010BBK-WESN

For Samsung T3 portable SSD, it is compatible with Windows, Mac OS, Android. 
I have installed "exfat-utils exfat-fuse" on Ubuntu. It can access the 250M read-only partition of the T3 SSD. No more.
I understand it is because Samsung T3 does not plan to support Ubuntu.

I searched around for one SSD external drive with hardware encryption that support Ubuntu, but failed to find one.
Any help?

Comment: You probably won't find much - software encryption may be your only option.

Comment: ...and software encryption may be your best option: https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/doh-what-my-encrypted-drive-can-be-unlocked-by-anyone-a495f6653581